# How to loop through object fields in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I want to avoid doing this:

```
handleUserChange?.({ target: { name: 'first_name', value: rentalOrder?.address?.first_name } })
handleUserChange?.({ target: { name: 'last_name', value: rentalOrder?.address?.last_name } })
handleUserChange?.({ target: { name: 'address_line_one', value: rentalOrder?.address?.address_line_one } })
```

So instead I have:

```
const fieldsFromDeliveryAddress = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'address_line_one', 'post_code', 'city', 'phone']
fieldsFromDeliveryAddress.forEach(fieldName => handleUserChange?.({ target: { name: fieldName, value: rentalOrder?.address?.[fieldName] } }))
```

But it gives me the TypeScript error (on line 2, `rentalOrder?.address?.[fieldName]` is underlined in red):

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ first_name: string; last_name: string; email?: string | undefined; address_line_one: string; address_line_two?: string | undefined; country: string; city: string; post_code: string; phone: string; }'.

No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ first_name: string; last_name: string; email?: string | undefined; address_line_one: string; address_line_two?: string | undefined; country: string; city: string; post_code: string; phone: string; }'
```

How can I solve this?

### Update

Function signatures:

```
const handleUserChange = ({ target }: HTMLSimpleElementEvent): void

interface HTMLSimpleElementEvent {
  target: {
    name: string
    type?: string
    value?: any
    checked?: boolean
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the type signature of handleUserChange?  On what line do you get this error?

Comment: @ShamPooSham It's on line 2, see updated question

Comment: Try to do `const fieldsFromDeliveryAddress = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'address_line_one', 'post_code', 'city', 'phone'] as const`. Does that work?

Comment: @ShamPooSham Yes! If you add an Answer I will upvote

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `as const`. Typescript will treat your array as a tuple and you'll have proper types for your forEach callback.

```
const fieldsFromDeliveryAddress = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'address_line_one', 'post_code', 'city', 'phone'] as const;
fieldsFromDeliveryAddress.forEach(fieldName => handleUserChange?.({ target: { name: fieldName, value: rentalOrder?.address?.[fieldName] } }))
```